# Handle 1000 concurrent requests for Flask/Gunicorn web service

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am fairly new to creating web services in Python. I have created a Flask web service successfully and run it with Gunicorn (as Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production).
This is how I run my app (with 4 worker nodes).

```
   gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 My_Web_Service:app -w 4
```

The problem is, this only handles 4 requests at a time. I want it to be able to handle potentially 1000's of requests concurrently. Should I be using multi-threading? Any other options/suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Reading the section on [Workers](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html) you have to switch to an async worker, which can handle thousands of connections, if your work is IO bound. Using more processes than CPUs is not recommended.

Comment: sure! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hi, so I tried using gevent async workers like this:
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 service:app -k gevent --worker-connections 1000
This works, but it still seems to process incoming requests sequentially.
For eg, when I pass 2 requests simultaneously and log times for each, I observe that the service one request at a time and starts serving another request after first one is done.

Comment: Do you understand, how gevent works? What kind of request do you answer? How do you profile your server?

Comment: I am new to using Gunicorn and Gevent. I googled about creating async workers and a few links recommended me to use Gevent.
I have used Flask to create a web service. I have defined 2 endpoints for 2 different types of processes.
The problem is, if I try to send requests to both the endpoints, it waits for the first request to process and respond and then processes the second request after the first one is done.
I think it's still doing Sync instead of Async.

Comment: I am facing same issue and not solved yet. Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch from Flask to FastAPI and combine it with either Async IO or (if it's not possible to find [non-blocking versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757497/simplest-async-await-example-possible-in-python) for all your functions) with a [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) (not multithreading, which would be still blocked by the GIL and thus [slightly slower](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-13-the-gil-and-its-effects-on-python-multithreading/)).

Among production servers `gunicorn` is probably still the best process manager, but since FastAPI needs ASGI, you need to combine it with [uvicorn workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/).