# coroutine was never awaited discord.py

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

Hi i'm  having trouble with my function `check_thunes()` it raises an error coroutine was never awaited

`check_thunes()` is fonction to check if the player input right value and if not send a message to inform the player. I need to apply it to other game later. I made the fonction async to be able to send message.
this is my code :

```
import discord
import time
from random import randrange,choices
import os
from replit import db
from keep_alive import keep_alive   


token = os.environ['token']
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("le bot est prêt")

@client.event
async def check_thunes(mise,joueur):
  if joueur in db.keys(): #trouve la thune du joueur dans la  db
      thune=int(db[joueur])
  else:
    db[joueur]="1000"
    thune=int(db[joueur])
    reste=str(thune-mise)
    db[joueur]=reste

  if mise<=0:
    await message.channel.send("Vous ne pouvez pas miser 0 crédit")
    return erreur 

  if thune<=0:
    await message.channel.send("Vous n'avez plus d'thune, mais voici un coup de pouce de 1k")
    db[joueur]=str(1000)
    return

  if mise>thune:
    await message.channel.send("Vous n'avez pas assez d'thune")
    return

  reste=str(thune-mise)
  db[joueur]=reste
  return reste,thune

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    msg=message.content
    if msg.startswith("!roulette") :
      
      #le message doir se présenter sous la forme
      # !roulette nb(0,50) mise(1,thune)

      gain=0
      thune=0
      reste=0
      nombre=""
      mise=""
      joueur=str(message.author.name)
      nb_g=int(randrange(51))
      erreur=0

      for i in range(10, 12): #trouve le nombre choisit
        nombre+=msg[i]
      nombre=int(nombre)

      for i in range(12,len(msg)): #trouve la mise
        mise+=msg[i]
      mise=int(mise)

      if joueur in db.keys(): #trouve la thune du joueur dans la  db
        thune=int(db[joueur])
      else:
        db[joueur]="1000"
        thune=int(db[joueur])
        reste=str(thune-mise)
        db[joueur]=reste

      #controleur des valeurs choisies
      if nombre>50:
        await message.channel.send("Le nombre choisit doit être entre 0 et 50")
        return
      
      check_thunes(mise, joueur)

      #calcul des gains
      if nombre==nb_g : #regza le premier gagnant du bot
        gain=mise*2

      elif (nombre%2==0 and nb_g%2==0) or (nombre%2==1 and nb_g%2==1 ) :
        gain=round(mise*1.25)
      else :
        gain=0

      if int(reste)+int(gain)>=0:
        db[joueur]=str(int(reste)+int(gain))
      elif int(reste)+int(gain)<0:
        db[joueur]=str(0)
        await message.channel.send("Vous n'avez plus d'thune")
        return

      if gain-mise>=0 :
        await message.channel.send(str("Vous aviez choisit "+str(nombre)+" et la roulette a donnée "+str(nb_g)))
        await message.channel.send(str("Vous avez gagné "+str(gain-mise)))
        await message.channel.send(str("Il vous reste "+str(int(reste)+gain)))
        return
      
      else:
        await message.channel.send(str("Vous aviez choisit "+str(nombre)+" et la roulette a donnée "+str(nb_g)))
        await message.channel.send(str("Vous avez perdu "+str(-(gain-mise))))
        await message.channel.send(str("Il vous reste "+str(int(reste)+gain)))
        return
```

Can you help me

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, it's a coroutine, you're supposed to `await` it...

Comment: sorry but i'm new to async fonction so i don't know how to fix this

Comment: Simple -- just add the `await` keyword before calling it: `await check_thunes(mise, joueur)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your function as a [`coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html), like this:

```
async def myFunction():
    ...
```

So, if you want to call it, you have to [`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757497/simplest-async-await-example-possible-in-python) it, like this:

```
await myFunction()
```

In your case, you simply have to add `await` before calling `check_thunes`, like [Łukasz Kwieciński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13131047/%C5%81ukasz-kwieci%C5%84ski) suggested:

```
await check_thunes(mise, joueur)
```