# Using contextvar to keep track of async loop in Python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, python-contextvars

I am trying to work with a simple async example in Python, largely following [this excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53420574/5123111).

My goal is to set up a context variable and keep track of the series of calls by continuously appending to it. I know that context variables can be accessed with the `.get()` method and their values altered with the `.set()` method. In the below case however, the variable doesn't get modified despite the series of calls to the function `sum()` that is apparent from the console.

**Edit:**
Based on Michael Butscher's comment below I replaced the original context variable (which was a string) with a list: `output_list` and modified the list iteratively using `.append()`. This now does enable me to view the final output but not the intermediate ones in the individual `sum()` methods.

Full code:

```
import asyncio
import contextvars
import time

output_list = contextvars.ContextVar('output_list', default=list())

async def sleep():
    print(f'Time: {time.time() - start:.2f}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def sum(name, numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        print(f'Task {name}: Computing {total}+{number}')
        await sleep()
        total += number
    output_list.set(output_list.get().append(f"{name}"))
    print(f'Task {name}: Sum = {total}\n')
    print(f'Partial output from task {name}:', output_list.get())

start = time.time()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    loop.create_task(sum("A", [1, 2])),
    loop.create_task(sum("B", [1, 2, 3])),
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()

end = time.time()
print(f'Time: {end-start:.2f} sec')
print("Final output_str =", output_list.get())
```

How can I iteratively follow the expansion of the context variable list `output_list`?

My desired console output is:

```
Task A: Computing 0+1
Time: 0.00
Task B: Computing 0+1
Time: 0.00
Task A: Computing 1+2
Time: 1.02
Task B: Computing 1+2
Time: 1.02
Task A: Sum = 3

Partial output from task A: ['A']
Task B: Computing 3+3
Time: 2.02
Task B: Sum = 6

Partial output from task B: ['A', 'B']
Time: 3.03 sec
Final output_str = ['A', 'B']
```

Instead, I am getting:

```
Task A: Computing 0+1
Time: 0.00
Task B: Computing 0+1
Time: 0.00
Task A: Computing 1+2
Time: 1.02
Task B: Computing 1+2
Time: 1.02
Task A: Sum = 3

Partial output from task A: None
Task B: Computing 3+3
Time: 2.02
Task B: Sum = 6

Partial output from task B: None
Time: 3.03 sec
Final output_str = ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Each task has its own context. Instead of a string you can set "output_str" to a list before creating the tasks and then only modify the list instead of replacing it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you, that's very useful advice. I edited my comment. I manage now to get the final output in order but I find that I still cannot record the intermediate states.

Comment: During the tasks you must not modify the content of the context variable (using "set" method), only modify the list. By the way: (1) The result of "list.append" is always "None". (2) Instead of setting a list as default for the context variable set the list explicitly before creating the tasks. Otherwise all future tasks will use the same list which may not be desired.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher. So does it mean there is actually no need to define `contextvars` at all?

Comment: If you have to manage multiple contexts with different variable contents (e. g. different lists) you need context variables. In your code a global variable would work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `asyncio` documentation:

> Tasks support the contextvars module. When a Task is created it copies the current context and later runs its coroutine in the copied context.

So, if you declare at the top of your program `cvar = contextvars.ContextVar('cvar', default='x')`, when you create a task, this will copy the current context, and if you modify `cvar` whithin it will just affect the copy but no the original context. That's the main reason why you got `''`(empty string) at your final output.

To achieve the "track" you want you must use a global variable in order to modify it anywhere. But if you want to play around with `asyncio` and `contextvars` to see how it works, see the example below:

```
import asyncio
import contextvars
import time

output = contextvars.ContextVar('output', default='No changes at all') 

async def sleep():
    print(f'Time: {time.time() - start:.2f}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def sum(name, numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        print(f'Task {name}: Computing {total}+{number}')
        await sleep()
        total += number
        output.set(output.get()+name) #Here we modify the respective context
    print(f'Task {name}: Sum = {total}\n')
    print(f'Partial output from task {name}:', output.get())
    return output.get() #Here we return the variable modified
start = time.time()

# main() will have its own copy of the context
async def main():
    output.set('Changed - ') # Change output var in this function context
    # task1 and task2 will copy this context (In this contect output=='Changed - ')
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(sum("A", [1, 2])) #This task has its own copy of the context of main()
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(sum("B", [1, 2, 3])) #This task also has its own copy of the context of main()
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait({task1,task2})
    resultTask1 = task1.result() # get the value of return of task1
    resultTask2 = task2.result() # get the value of return of task1
    print('Result1: ', resultTask1)
    print('Result2: ', resultTask2)
    print('Variable output in main(): ',output.get()) # However, output in main() is sitill 'Changed - '
    output.set(output.get()+'/'+resultTask1+'/'+resultTask2) #Modify the var in this context
    print('Variable modified in main(): ', output.get())
    return output.get() #Return modified value

x = asyncio.run(main()) # Assign the return value to x

end = time.time()
print(f'Time: {end-start:.2f} sec')
print("Final output (without changes) =", output.get())
output.set(x)
print("Final output (changed) =", output.get())

##### OUTPUT #####
# Time: 0.00
# Task B: Computing 0+1
# Time: 0.00
# Task A: Computing 1+2
# Time: 1.01
# Task B: Computing 1+2
# Time: 1.01
# Task A: Sum = 3

# Partial output from task A: Changed - AA
# Task B: Computing 3+3
# Time: 2.02
# Task B: Sum = 6

# Partial output from task B: Changed - BBB
# Result1:  Changed - AA
# Result2:  Changed - BBB
# Variable output in main():  Changed -
# Variable modified in main():  Changed - /Changed - AA/Changed - BBB
# Time: 3.03 sec
# Final output (without changes) = No changes at all
# Final output (changed) = Changed - /Changed - AA/Changed - BBB
```

As you can see, it is impossible to modify the same variable at the same time. While `task1` is modifying its copy, `task2` is modifying its copy too.