# How do I run python asynchronous script with poetry tool script?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-poetry, python-anyio

I want to run python asynchronous script with poetry tool script. Could you please help?
In `pyproject.toml`, I added like this.

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
clear_data = "clear_data.clear_data:main"
```

In my python file, I wrote like this.

```
from anyio import run

async def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main)
```

`

I have with poetry tool script. But faced this error.

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
  main()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to take a look at ["_Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/20170164)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Poetry, right?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way is to use sync entrypoint, which invokes async top-level function as per [Simplest async/await example possible in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757497/simplest-async-await-example-possible-in-python)

```py
import asyncio

async def run():
    pass

def main():
    asyncio.run(run())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works with my poetry tool.script.

```
    def main():
        asyncio.run(start())
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```